# Determine the maximum number of consecutive equal elements in a given array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, algorithm

Determine the maximum number of consecutive equal elements in a given array.

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1]
def recurring(arr)
    freq = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,v| h[v] += 1; h }
    freq.max_by { |k,v| v }
end
```

p recurring(ar

Comment: Do you wish to determine the maximum number of consecutive equal elements in a given array? If so, your first sentence is incorrect, and your code is not relevant and therefore misleading. You need to edit the question to clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def recurring(arr)
  elements = arr.uniq
  elements.map { |el| arr.count(el) }.max
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the task is to determine the maximum number of consecutive equal elements in a given array.

```
def recurring(arr)
  arr.chunk(&:itself).map { |_,a| a.size }.max
end

arr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1]
recurring arr
  #=> 5
```

[Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) was introduced in Ruby v2.2. For earlier versions, write

```
arr.chunk { |e| e }.map { |_,a| a.size }.max
```

The steps:

```
enum = arr.chunk(&:itself)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fbb04943088>:each>
```

We can see what elements will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [2, [2]], [3, [3, 3, 3]], [4, [4, 4]], [1, [1, 1]]]

b = enum.map { |_,a| a.size }
  #=> [5, 1, 3, 2, 2] 
b.max
  #=> 5
```